# Finding average with respect to the arc length

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates, parametrization, arc-length

## The Problem

There's an exercise in the MIT OCW 18.01SC course:

> What is the average distance from the $x$-axis of a point chosen at random on the cardioid $r = a (1 - \cos (\theta))$, if the point is chosen
>   b) by letting a point $P$ travel around the cardioid at uniform velocity, stopping at random;

I managed to find the answer correctly, my solution is long, but straightforward.
The solution given in the answers is much shorter, but I don't understand it.

## MIT Solution

In the proposed solution they are averaging the expression

$$ \frac 1 {8a} 
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} {| r \sin \theta | 
a \sqrt {2 - 2 \cos \theta} d\theta} $$

which is actually

$$ \frac 1 {8a} 
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} 
{ d(\theta) \frac {dw} {d\theta} d\theta }$$

as I understand because it stems from finding the arc length element $dw$ as:

$$ dw = 
{\sqrt
  {\left(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\right)^2 + 
   \left(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\right)^2
  } }
  d\theta \\
  = \sqrt { \left(\frac {dr} {d\theta}\right)^2 + r^2 } d\theta \\
  = a \sqrt {2 - 2 \cos \theta} d\theta$$

I don't quite understand their idea of finding the average.

[image: MIT Solution]

## My Solution

I considered just the upper part of the cardioid because of the symmetry: $\theta: 0 \dots \pi$.

I aimed to find the distance as a function of the arclength: $d(w)$ and calculate the average as
$$ \frac
{\int_{0}^{w(\pi)}{d(w) dw}}
{\int_{0}^{w(\pi)}{dw}} $$

As I know the distance as a function of $\theta$: $d(\theta) = r(\theta) sin(\theta)$, I wanted to find $\theta$ as the function of the arclength: $\theta(w)$.

I found at first 
$$w(\theta) = 
\int_0^{\theta}
{\sqrt
  {\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + 
   \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2
  }
  dt \\
= 4a (1 - \cos \frac \theta 2)
}
$$

Hence

$$ \theta = 2 \cos ^ {-1} (1 - \frac w {4a})  $$

Plugging it into 
$$ {\int_{0}^{w(\pi)}{d(w) dw}} = \\
{\int_{0}^{w(\pi)}{r(\theta) * \sin(\theta) dw}} $$

I integrated it using some trigonometry into the correct answer $\frac {4a} 5$

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjustOB to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @joriki thank you! Fixed that. If only it would help me to attract the answer :-D Actually your comment is very useful because I plan to use LaTeX in the future and it's easier to remember when you're getting pointed at something.

Comment: You've still got some sines in math italics. If you plan to use $\LaTeX$ in the future, [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) for MathJax on this site might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIT course result looks ok to me. A differential approach is shorter:

[image]

$$ r= a- a \cos \theta \tag1$$

Differentiate with respect to arc ($ \dfrac {dr}{ds}=\cos \psi )$ which is angle between tangent and and radius vector.

$$\cot \psi= a \sin \theta /r \tag2$$

where $\sin \theta $ is understood to be taken absolute value.

Average y-value numerator denominator is (total arc of cardioid is $8a$  ):

$$\int r \sin \theta \, ds =\int r \sin \theta \, \frac{ds}{d\theta} d\theta =\int r \sin \theta \, \frac {r}{\sin \psi} d\theta \tag3 $$

Plug in from (2) numerator
$$ \int r^2 \frac{\sin \theta}{\sin \psi} d\theta=\int
r^2 \sqrt{1+\cot{^2}\psi} \sin \theta d\theta = r \sqrt{r^2+ a^2 \sin^2 \theta}\, \sin \theta \,d \theta  \tag4 $$

Plug in from (1) and simplify
$$ \bar y = \int a^2 \sqrt2 \, (1-\cos \theta)^{3/2}\,|\sin\theta|  \,d \theta / (8a)\tag5 $$
and further.

Comment: Thank you, actually I think I don't 100% understand the idea of taking a $\frac {dr} {ds}$ that you used, but I'll figure it out. I wonder is this a standard idea to use in some calculus problems? I remember now that something similar was taught in the MIT 18.02SC "Multivariable Calculus" course when he analyzed the Kepler's second law derivation.

Comment: However actually I realized that it's not what my initial question was about, but they way you wrote it helped me to realize what is it that I don't understand.
It is hard for me to understand why is this legal (I converted to the definite integral)
$$\int_{s_0}^{s_1} r \sin \theta \, ds =\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1} r \sin \theta \, \frac{ds}{d\theta} d\theta $$
As I understand it, technically, it's just a substitution of a variable in a definite integral, we substituted for the equal differential and changed the limits accordingly.

Comment: What surprises me is that we didn't have to change the $r \sin \theta$ part! Now, realizing that it's technically correct, I think I understand where my confusion stems from! We are usually taught & we perform variable substitution in scenarios when for example integrating 
$$ \int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(x)\,dx =
\int_{0}^{4} x^2 2x\,dx =
\int_{0}^{16} u \,du
$$
the "$f(x)$" part changes from being expressed in terms of the original variable to being expressed in terms of the substituting variable.

Comment: In the substitution that you made here, the "integrated expression" was already in terms of the variable that we wished to substitute in! So you & MIT effectively changed the "differential part" and the limits (which was easier and more elegant) whereas I stubbornly insisted on expressing the "integrated expression" in terms of the variable of the original differential. Sorry for a lot of words, but I think now you've finally helped me to understand the maneuver that confused me!

Comment: Glad it helped. $ u = \int \dfrac{du}{dt} dt $ etc.  is a convenient way dealing with differentials. This works in ratios in differential triangles as indicated in the edited sketch. An obvious typo corrected.